# Match multiple line string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl and I was wondering if someone can help me.

I have an input like this:

```
a,b,
c,d,e,f,g,h,
i,j,q // Letras
```

I'm trying to get the letters before `//` separately and then print them between `{}` separated by `:`.

I tried with this RE `([\w,;:\s\t]*)(\n|\/\/)/m` and I could get in `$1` all letters for each line (as a string including separators) but not what I want.

I need to match that pattern more than one time in the same file so I was using `/g`.

Edit:

Here is my code block:

```
while ( <> ) {
  if ( /([\w,;:\s\t]*)(\n|\/\/)/m ) {
    print "$1\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Could we see what you have tried so far?

Comment: while(<>){
 if (/([\w,;:\s\t]*)(\n|\/\/)/m){
  print "$1\n";
 }
}


With this I could print the content before //.

Answer (score 2):

`/m` is for using `^`, and `$` to match by line in a string with multiple lines.

On the other hand, you are reading the input **line by line**. You cannot expect to match across lines with a single expression if you only look at **one line at a time**.

Instead, read by chunks by setting `$/` to an appropriate value. If the chunks always end in the exact string `"// Letras\n\n"`, the task is even simpler.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '//';

while (my $chunk = <DATA>) {
    chomp $chunk;
    my @fields = ($chunk =~ /([a-z])[, ]/g);
    next unless @fields;
    printf "{%s}\n", join(':', @fields);
}

__DATA__
a,b,
c,d,e,f,g,h,
i,j,q // Letras

a,b,
c,d,e,f,g,h,
i,j,q // Metras
```

Output:

```
{a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:q}
{a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:q}
```

You can also use [File::Stream](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Stream):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Stream;

my $stream = File::Stream->new(
    \*DATA,
    separator => qr{ (?: \s+ // [^\n]+ ) \n\n }x
);

while (my $chunk = <$stream>) {
    $chunk =~ s{ \s+ // .* \z }{}sx;
    $chunk =~ s{ ,\n? }{:}gx;
    print "{$chunk}\n";
}

__DATA__
a,b,
c,d,e,f,g,h,
i,j,q // Letras

a,b,
c,d,e,f,g,h,
i,j,q // Metras
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of speculation!

Comment: That's what I need! I didn't know how to read the file until read a '//'.
How works this piece of code: my $chunk = <DATA> ? What should be my DATA if I have an input .txt file?

Finally, how works this:  next unless @fields; ?
Thanks again!

Comment: Open the file using the usual `open my $fh, '<', $filename` ... Then use `$fh` instead of `DATA`.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're aiming for is to remove comments (denoted by a double slash) from each line, and print it out enclosed by braces, and with a colon `:` separator instead of commas

First of all you should remove the trailing linefeed character from each line using `chomp`

Then all you need to remove any trailing comment is `s|\s*//.*||`. That removes any spaces before the `//` as well. I'm using a pipe character `|` as the delimiter so as to avoid having to escape the slashes within the regex pattern. And the data is being processed one line at a time so there no need for the *global* `/g` modifier

This program reads from the file specified on the command line, which I've set up to contain the data you show in the question

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  s|\s*//.*||;
  print "{$_}\n";
}
```

**output**

```
{a,b,}
{c,d,e,f,g,h,}
{i,j,q}
```

---

**Update**

Thanks to [Sinan Ünür's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582468/622310) I notice that you've asked to *"print [the letters] between `{}` separated by `:`"*

This is a modification of the `while` loop above, which finds all substrings within the current line that don't contain commas, and joins them together again using colons `:`

```
while ( <> ) {
  chomp;
  s|\s*//.*||;
  my $values = join ':', /[^,]+/g;
  print "{$values}\n";
}
```

**output**

```
{a:b}
{c:d:e:f:g:h}
{i:j:q}
```

I am sure the true solution is much more simple, but unless you elaborate your question we have to cater for all possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to combine the letters on all 3 lines into the output, or convert each line?

In other words, is your desired output

```
{a:b}
{c:d:e:f:g:h}
{i:j:q}
```

or

```
{a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:q}
```

?

If you want the former, Borodin's answer works.
If you want the latter, then you should load the contents into an array, and print it using a join statement. To do that, I've modified Borodin's answer:

```
while ( <> ) {    # read each line
  chomp;          # remove \n from line
  s|\s*//.*||;    # remove comment
  push @values, ':', /[^,]+/g;   # store letters in array
}
my $values = join ':', @values;  # convert array to string
print "{$values}\n";             # print the results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = "a,b,
c,d,e,f,g,h,
i,j,q // Letras";

$str = join "",map {s/,/:/g ;(split)[0]}  split '\n', $str;

print "{$str}";


Sample output

{a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:q}
```

I am considering a string with multilines separated by newline character.

```
join "",map {s/,/:/g ;(split)[0]}  split '\n', $str
```

This is evaluated from right to left.

1. Split with `\n` on `$str` produces 3 elements which is input for `map`.
2. `(split)[0]` : default delimiter for `split` is whitespace. so each element is split for whitespace and `0th` element is only considered discarding others.
   Ex `(split)[0]` for `i,j,q // Letras` produces 3 elements "i,j,q" "//" "Letras" where only element 0 i.e., "i,j,q" is considered.
3. `,` is replaced with `:`
4. `join` is used to combine all the resulting elements from `map`.